# preg_replace does not give good results

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a SQL file that contains lines with the word CONSTRAINT. 
I want to remove all lines that begin with 'CONSTRAINT' and the comma (,) of the previous line, for example:

```
KEY `fk_node_node_type1_idx` (`tid`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user` (`uid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_node_language1` FOREIGN KEY (`language`) REFERENCES `language` (`language`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_node_node_type1` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `node_type` (`tid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

...
...

```
KEY `fk_node_type_data_idx` (`tid`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_node_type_data` FOREIGN KEY (`tid`) REFERENCES `node_type` (`tid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

...
...

```
KEY `fk_node_has_image_node1_idx` (`nid`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_node_has_image_node1` FOREIGN KEY (`nid`) REFERENCES `node` (`nid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_node_has_image_image1` FOREIGN KEY (`fid`) REFERENCES `file` (`fid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

here is my code:

> preg_replace("/,\s(.*)CONSTRAINT(.*)/" , "" , $string);

it works well on a single line, but when you have two or three successive line, it does not work well.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
echo preg_replace("/,\v+CONSTRAINT .*?(?=,\v|$)/i","",$string);
```

Comment: I think you'd need: `echo preg_replace('/,(\v+CONSTRAINT .*?(?=,\v|$))/mi', '$1', $string);` - [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zR5cV5)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Ah right, but I don't think your `preg_replace()` would work either. Not sure why though.

Comment: your pattern can be shorten to `/,\v+CONSTRAINT .*/i`, `\v` is a good idea.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That won't remove the comma on the previous line, only on the current line - important difference if the `CONSTRAINT` line is the last one!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: refresh the page, I have made several changes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Now you're taking the comma off the line before, and the current line. This won't allow multiple lines of `CONSTRAINT`s to be removed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Indeed, I have seen the problem and posted a correct pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
preg_replace("/,\s?CONSTRAINT[^,]*/s" , "" , $string);
```

[Regexpal demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gs&regex=,%5Cs?CONSTRAINT%5B%5E,%5D%2a&input=CONSTRAINT%5B%5E,%5D%2aKEY%20%60fk_node_node_type1_idx%60%20%28%60tid%60%29,%0ACONSTRAINT%20%60fk_pages_users1%60%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20%28%60uid%60%29%20REFERENCES%20%60user%60%20%28%60uid%60%29%20ON%20DELETE%20NO%20ACTION%20ON%20UPDATE%20NO%20ACTION,%0ACONSTRAINT%20%60fk_node_language1%60%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20%28%60language%60%29%20REFERENCES%20%60language%60%20%28%60language%60%29%20ON%20DELETE%20NO%20ACTION%20ON%20UPDATE%20NO%20ACTION,%0ACONSTRAINT%20%60fk_node_node_type1%60%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20%28%60tid%60%29%20REFERENCES%20%60node_type%60%20%28%60tid%60%29%20ON%20DELETE%20NO%20ACTION%20ON%20UPDATE%20NO%20ACTION)

Comment: `s` is the DOTALL modifier. Your regex has no `.` in it. Therefore `s` is pointless.

Comment: Quite correct. I'm mistaking my /s and /m. But since the caret and dollar aren't being used, it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @jawad, what line ends do you have on your file? CR or LF (i.e.: are you running Windows, MacOS or Linux)?

Comment: I test under easyphp windows.

Comment: Updated to just check for \s (and not \n since you might only have \r line ends).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~,\RCONSTRAINT .*(?<!,)~', '', $string);
```